# Pipeline data processing and code architecture

Tags: python, design-patterns, pipeline, feature-extraction

I am currently working for my PhD on a Python package that extracts multiple features from data. Each feature can be defined as a pipeline of mathematical operations, which can take some parameters. The results of those operations are needed by different features, and I would like to avoid computational cost (at the moment this is not a problem, but at some point I will have to process a lot of data). Is there a way of structuring my code so that those shared operations are only computed once ?

Here is an illustration :
[Pipelines of operations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EySg.png)

In this example, Operation 1 with Parameter = Value 1 only needs to be computed once, and the result is used in different pipelines which lead to 3 different features at the end. Also in this example Operation 3 needs implicitely the result of Operation 2.

For the moment, my solution is that all my operations inherits from a `PipelineElement` class, which have a `parent` attribute and a `children` attribute. This way I can create a tree of operations and only compute it once. Is it the way ? Is this pattern frequently used and if so where can I learn some good practices ?

Comment: The general principle you're looking for is a _Dependency Graph_, and your specific case is a _Data Flow Graph_ (the data flows through the graph in the opposite direction to the dependency arrows). Searching those terms should get you started, and yes it's a known pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to be something in the middle of a Strategy, Composite, or Visitor pattern as defined in the "Gang of four" design pattern book. It is an old, but still relevant book. Its official name is "**Design Patterns
Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software**" By Erich Gamma, Richard Helm, Ralph Johnson, John Vlissides. 1994.

You can find a fine resume of these patterns in:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/gangs-of-four-gof-design-patterns#behavioral-design-patterns